# Find list element when page is loaded

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, splistitem

I'm trying to get an element once page has been loaded. However when I put the code in `window.onload = function () { my code };` it's not working, without `window.onload`it get's the element. here's my code:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    var itemId = 12;
    var targetListItem;
    var ref;
    //with window.onload
    window.onload = function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', runCode);
    }
    //without window.onload
    //SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', runCode);
    function runCode() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
        var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Employees');
        targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
        clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Name');
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded,onQueryFailed);
   }
   function onQuerySucceeded() {
        ref = targetListItem.get_item('Name');
        alert(ref)
   }
   function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Error');
   }
</script>
```

When I run the in `window.onload` I get the error:

```
Request failed.
Error: Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
StackTrace: undefined
```

The item exists in the list.
Does anyone know why is it like that? Thanks.
**EDIT**
I've noticed that the code with `window.onload` works when the page is in edit mode. The code breaks at line `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', runCode);` in `windows.onload`.

Comment: Check whether there is item with ID= 12 existing in the list

Comment: Yes, I have checked and the item exists there. Why would it then get the item if I'm running the code without window.onload?

Comment: The itemID is defined as a global object. I think that object is getting modified somehow. Try to alert the value before executing the query and make sure it remains 12.

Comment: @AmalHashim No that's not the case. I've also passed 12 straight in getItemById method. Had the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small utility to attach properly to the SharePoint lifecycle.

You use it like this:

```
window.LifeCycleHelper.AttachToLoad(function(){ alert('Hello World'); });
```

Utility:

```
//use an IIFE to create a scope and dont dirty the global scope
(function (_) {
    // use strict to ensure we dont code stupid
    'use strict';

    var initHandlers = [];
    var initMDSHandlers = [];

    var ensureSharePoint = function (handler) {
        var sodLoaded = typeof (_v_dictSod) !== 'undefined' && _v_dictSod['sp.js'] != null && _v_dictSod['sp.js'].state === Sods.loaded;

        if (sodLoaded) {
            handler();
        } else {
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { });
            SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(handler, 'sp.js');
        }
    };

    var initMDS = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < initMDSHandlers.length; i++) {
            initMDSHandlers[i]();
        }
    };

    var init = function () {
        // Register MDS handler
        if ('undefined' != typeof g_MinimalDownload && g_MinimalDownload && (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase()).endsWith('/_layouts/15/start.aspx') && 'undefined' != typeof asyncDeltaManager) {
            asyncDeltaManager.add_endRequest(initMDS);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < initHandlers.length; i++) {
                initHandlers[i]();
            }
        }
    };

    var registerInit = function (handler) {
        initHandlers.push(handler);
    };

    var registerInitMDS = function (handler) {
        initMDSHandlers.push(handler);
    };

    var domReady = (function (handler) {
        var fns = [];
        var listener;
        var loaded = (document.documentElement.doScroll ? /^loaded|^c/ : /^loaded|^i|^c/).test(document.readyState);

        if (!loaded) {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', listener = function () {
                document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', listener);
                loaded = 1;
                while (listener = fns.shift()) listener();
            });
        }

        return function (fn) {
            loaded ? setTimeout(fn, 0) : fns.push(fn);
        };
    })();


    var attachToLoad = function (functionToAttach) {
        registerInit(functionToAttach);
        registerInitMDS(functionToAttach);
       domReady(function () {
           init();
        });
    };

    _.AttachToLoad = attachToLoad;

    // THIS WILL PROTECT YOUR GLOBAL VAR FROM THE GARBAGE COLLECTOR
    window.LifeCycleHelper = _;
    if (window.Function != 'undefined' && typeof (Function.registerNamespace) == 'function') {
        Function.registerNamespace('LifeCycleHelper');
    }
})({});

var theCodeYouWantToRun = function () {
    alert('theCodeYouWantToRun');
};

window.LifeCycleHelper.AttachToLoad(theCodeYouWantToRun);
```

[More Information on how to work with lifecycle and MDS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/181408/10271)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. All or the functions has to be inside `window.onload = function ()`. Then it works.

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    var itemId = 12;
    var targetListItem;
    var ref;
    //with window.onload
    window.onload = function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', runCode);

    //without window.onload
    //SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', runCode);
    function runCode() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
        var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Employees');
        targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
        clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Name');
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded,onQueryFailed);
   }
   function onQuerySucceeded() {
        ref = targetListItem.get_item('Name');
        alert(ref)
   }
   function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Error');
   }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: The way you attach is not best practise and will not work in certain scenarios (MDS for example).